# Sorting A->Z, Letters Before Numbers?

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-2010, customization

I have a task list with a DUE date column. The column has dates and blanks, and also sometimes an "ASAP". I can sort the list from Oldest to Newest, or A->Z, and the most imminent dates are placed on top and the blanks are on the bottom. This is what is intended. However, the "ASAP" tasks are placed between the dates and the blanks. I assume this is because Excel sorts numbers first and then letters.

How can I sort the list so that the highest-priority tasks with the "ASAP" note appear at the top of the list when sorting A->Z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest solution is to add a helper column that functions as you expected. For example you can add a column to the right and fill that with an if statement like this:

```
IF(A5="ASAP";1;0)
```

And apply it to all of the cell in the helper column to generate a new column that holds 1 for ASAP and 0 other wise. Then you can sort it first on this helper column then on the due date column.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That does the trick! I've included a macro that sorts the two column sequentially. Thanks for the help!